# how to insert sequential rows in data.table in R (Example given)?

Tags: r, data.table

df is data.table and df_expected is desired data.table . I want to add hour column from 0 to 23 and visits value would be filled as 0 for hours newly added .

```
df<-data.table(customer=c("x","x","x","y","y"),location_id=c(1,1,1,2,3),hour=c(2,5,7,0,4),visits=c(40,50,60,70,80))






df_expected<-data.table(customer=c("x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x",
                               "y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y",
                               "y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y","y"),

                    location_id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                                  2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
                                  3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),

                    hour=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,
                           0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,
                           0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23),

                    visits=c(0,0,40,0,0,50,0,60,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                             70,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                             0,0,0,0,80,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

This is what I tried to obtain my result , but it did not work

```
df1<-df[,':='(hour=seq(0:23)),by=(customer)]
Error in `[.data.table`(df, , `:=`(hour = seq(0L:23L)), by = (customer)) : 
Type of RHS ('integer') must match LHS ('double'). To check and coerce would impact 
performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or 
coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that creates the target and then uses a join to add in the visits information. The `ifelse` statement just helps up clean up the `NA` from the merge. You could also leave them in and replace them with `:=` in the new data.table.

```
target <- data.table(
  customer = rep(unique(df$customer), each = 24),
  hour = 0:23)

df_join <- df[target, on = c("customer", "hour"), 
   .(customer, hour, visits = ifelse(is.na(visits), 0, visits))
   ]

all.equal(df_expected, df_join)
```

**Edit:**

This addresses the request to include the `location_id` column. One way to do this is with `by=location` in the creation of the target. I've also added in some of the code from chinsoon12's answer.

```
target <- df[ , .("customer" = rep(unique(customer), each = 24L),
                  "hour" = rep(0L:23L, times = uniqueN(customer))),
              by = location_id]

df_join <- df[target, on = .NATURAL, 
              .(customer, location_id, hour, visits = fcoalesce(visits, 0))]

all.equal(df_expected, df_join)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , have one query though .. I have one more column called "location_id" and it is related to customer column ....it is like 1 customer may have 3 location_ids , other customer have just 1 location_id ....In such scenario how do I make changes to above script because customer with 1 location would be repeated 24 times , and customer with 3 locations would be repeated 72 times (24*3)....

Comment: You're welcome. Please see my edit for a way to include an additional column.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `CJ` to generate your universe, `on=.NATURAL` for joining on identically named columns, and `fcoalesce` to handle NAs:

```
df[CJ(customer, hour=0L:23L, unique=TRUE), on=.NATURAL, allow.cartesian=TRUE, 
    .(customer=i.customer, hour=i.hour, visits=fcoalesce(visits, 0))]
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a for-loop answer.

```
df_final <- data.table()
for(i in seq(24)){
  if(i %in% df[,hour]){
    a <- df[hour==i]
  }else{
    a <- data.table(customer="x", hour=i, visits=0)}

  df_final <- rbind(df_final, a)
}
df_final
```

You can wrap this in another for-loop to have your multiple customers x, y, etc. (the following loop isnt very clean but gets the job done).

```
df_final <- data.table()

for(j in unique(df[,customer])){

  for(i in seq(24)){

    if(i %in% df[,hour]){
      if(df[hour==i,customer] %in% j){
        a <- df[hour==i]
      }else{
        a <- data.table(customer=j, hour=i, visits=0)
      }
    }else{
      a <- data.table(customer=j, hour=i, visits=0)
    }

    df_final <- rbind(df_final, a)
  }
}

df_final
```